# How to set angular 2+ dropdown default value? [ Existing questions did not answer my problem ]

Tags: html, angular, dropdown

When I try to set a default value with empty value like below, its working

```
destChannelList = [
    {
      "channelId":"",
      "channelName":"SMS"
    },
    {
      "channelId":1,
      "channelName":"Voice"
    },
    {
      "channelId":2,
      "channelName":"FaceBook"
    }
  ];
```

But when I have a channelId with a value like below, its not selecting the first value:

```
destChannelList = [
    {
      "channelId":0,
      "channelName":"SMS"
    },
    {
      "channelId":1,
      "channelName":"Voice"
    },
    {
      "channelId":2,
      "channelName":"FaceBook"
    }
  ];
```

Please see the sample code here :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mribg5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Please note I know there are lot of questions on this issue, none solved my problem. Please don't flag as duplicate. Share me the link to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor set the values to model variable

```
constructor(){
 this.selectedDestChannel = this.destChannelList[0].channelId
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mribg5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you @sachila.

Comment: make sure to check as answer if this helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Your dropdown ngValue is **"channelId"** from array of object.

the default value should be match with any of  "channelId" in array of objects.

When

```
selectedDestChannel = '';
```

matches with

```
{
  "channelId":"",
  "channelName":"SMS"
},
```

set default value equal to any of  "channelId" like this

```
name = 'Angular';
destChannelList = [
  {
    "channelId":0,
    "channelName":"SMS"
  },
  {
    "channelId":1,
    "channelName":"Voice"
  },
  {
    "channelId":2,
    "channelName":"FaceBook"
  }
];
selectedDestChannel : any;
constructor(){
   //set default;
   this.selectedDestChannel = this.destChannelList[0].channelId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Raja, now I understood what went wrong. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

In your `component.ts`

```
constructor(){
  this.selectedDestChannel = this.destChannelList[0].channelId;
}
```

In your `component.html`

```
<select name="destchannel" nglFormControl [(ngModel)]="selectedDestChannel" required>
  <option *ngFor="let destchannel of destChannelList" [ngValue]="destchannel.channelId" [selected]="destchannel.channelName == 'SMS'">{{destchannel.channelName}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Harunur, I did initialized this.selectedDestChannel = this.destChannelList[0].channelId; but in class not in ngOnInit(), now its working fine. Thanks Once again.